# Adding links to login page of Coova captive portal

Tags: configuration, portal, openwrt, captivenetwork

I have set up a Coova hotspot with captive portal. Presently, it is configured to internal hotspot and the webpages for captive portal are self-contained in the router. I am able to successfully login, browse and logout of the network.

I would like to add a  to the login page, when clicked will open my company's webpage (all this, before the authentication happens). I added simple HTML code (below) to the 'Login Page' html code present in the portal.

```
<a href="www.mycompany.com"> My Company </a>
```

I also added 'www.mycompany.com' in the walled garden inorder to allow access before the authentication succeeds.

When clicked on the link, it fails to open the desired webpage. It tries to search the page inside the router. But I can access the same page if type it in the browser. Please advise me how to customize the portal when using it as internal hotspot. Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.. I had to give the complete address as the link - "http://mycompany.com".